# What is a word like "belies" but means "accidentally reveals"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like naming an object **Foo** *accidentally reveals* its relationship to **Bar**.

Comment: Is belies appropriate in that sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think *betrays* would work here; *naming the object Foo betrays its relationship to Bar*.

Comment: Snap :)  You beat me to it @Connor Harris

Comment: Betray is one of the "definitions" of belie. Does that mean either word is appropriate in this context?

Comment: Not exact synonyms I think @wrhall.  My face may belie my age, but that is surely entirely different from betraying it?

Answer (score 1):

Betrays.

E.g. naming an object passwordHint betrays its relationship to anActualPassword.

Answer (score 1):

Unmasks.

E.g. naming an object latinate unmasks its relationship to a certain dead language.